# Understanding Elixir badarg error message

Tags: erlang, elixir

When trying to start my process from a `DynamicSupervisor` im getting the following error:

```
{:error,
 {:EXIT,
  {:badarg,
   [
     {:erlang, :apply,
      [
        BfgEngine.MarketService,
        :start_link,
        {{BfgEngine.MarketService, :start_link, ["1111"]}, :permanent, 5000,
         :worker, [BfgEngine.MarketService]}
      ], []},
     {:supervisor, :do_start_child_i, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 379]},
     {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 404]},
     {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 661]},
     {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 690]},
     {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}
   ]}}}
```

The code im using is:

```
  def start_market(market_id) do
    spec = {MarketService, market_id}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
  end
```

However it is not clear to me what is going wrong. What argument to which function is it thats not correct? How do I break down and read the given error message?

Update:

This is the init method of my supervisor:

```
  @impl true
  def init(initial_arg) do
    DynamicSupervisor.init(
      strategy: :one_for_one,
      extra_arguments: [initial_arg]
    )
  end
```

Update 2:
This is the start_link of market_service:

```
  def start_link(market_id) when is_bitstring(market_id) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, market_id, name: via_tuple(market_id))
  end
```

Im using the default `child_spec` im getting from `GenServer`

Update 3:
Changing to:

```
  def start_market(market_id) do
    spec = {MarketService, market_id: market_id}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
  end
```

Gives:

```
{:error,
 {:undef,
  [
    {BfgEngine.MarketService, :start_link, [[], [market_id: "222"]], []},
    {DynamicSupervisor, :start_child, 3,
     [file: 'lib/dynamic_supervisor.ex', line: 654]},
    {DynamicSupervisor, :handle_start_child, 2,
     [file: 'lib/dynamic_supervisor.ex', line: 640]},
    {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 661]},
    {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 690]},
    {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}
  ]}}
```

Changing to:

```
  def start_market(market_id) do
    spec = {MarketService, :market_id, market_id}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
  end
```

Gives:

```
** (ArgumentError) supervisors expect each child to be one of:

  * a module
  * a {module, arg} tuple
  * a child specification as a map with at least the :id and :start fields
  * or a tuple with 6 elements generated by Supervisor.Spec (deprecated)

Got: {BfgEngine.MarketService, :market_id, "222"}

    (elixir) lib/supervisor.ex:657: Supervisor.init_child/1
    (elixir) lib/supervisor.ex:744: Supervisor.child_spec/2
    (elixir) lib/dynamic_supervisor.ex:304: DynamicSupervisor.start_child/2
```

Comment: Could you share the definition of your Supervisor's `init` function as well?

Comment: The problem is in the `start_link` code of your `MarketService`. The things to look at there are your start_link function as well as your child_spec. Can you add those to your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell from posted code, but could you try changing `start_market` to:

```
  def start_market(market_id) do
    spec = {MarketService, :market_id, market_id}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
  end
```

UPDATE (Below are two options):

```
  def start_market(market_id) do
    spec = &{
      id: MarketService,
      start: {MarketService, start_link, [market_id]},
      type: :worker
    }
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
  end
```

OR

```
  def start_market(market_id) do
    spec = {MarketService, [market_id]}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
  end
```

Comment: I have updated with some examples where I get a different error now.

Comment: you din't use my code. it should be only tuple `{MarketService, :market_id, market_id}` and not `{MarketService, market_id: market_id}` those are two diferent data structures. Please notice comma after :market_id atom!

Comment: I know this is old, but, I updated answer. This should be correct now

Answer (score 1):

You got `badarg` exception to function `erlang:apply/3` when there are three arguments `BfgEngine.MarketService`, `:start_link` and `{{BfgEngine.MarketService, :start_link, ["1111"]}, :permanent, 5000, :worker, [BfgEngine.MarketService]}` and it happen in function `supervisor:do_start_child_i/3`.

The arguments to the function `erlang:apply/3` should be MFA a.k.a Module, Function, Arguments. `{{BfgEngine.MarketService, :start_link, ["1111"]}, :permanent, 5000, :worker, [BfgEngine.MarketService]}` is not Arguments because it obviously is not a **list of arguments**. From your code, I can guess the error is the content of variable `spec`. You should provide some proplist or map. I don't know, you should read the documentation of `DynamicSupervisor` more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

## The error message

As of understanding the error message thrown by Elixir, you can refer to [the official Erlang documentation](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html#exit-reasons). The section about [errors and exceptions](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-exceptions) from Learn You Some Erlang For Great Good can help. The answer of `@Hynek -Pichi Vychodil` is also accurate.

## Your specific problem

As `@Milan Jaric` mentioned, your error would come from:

```
  def start_market(market_id) do
    spec = {MarketService, market_id}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
  end
```

But not only! `DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)` is calling `MarketService.start_link/1`! 
Your problem lies in the combination of this function from the DynamicSupervisor module, and the way you parse values in MarketService.start_link/1:

```
  def start_link(market_id) when is_bitstring(market_id) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, market_id, name: via_tuple(market_id))
  end
```

Indeed, this code *should* work, if you also have implemented MarketService.init/1 correctly. I am not able to reproduce the error. Are you sure `market_id` is really a bitstring?

Personally, I had based my code on the [official documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DynamicSupervisor.html#module-migrating-from-supervisors-simple_one_for_one):

```
defmodule MySupervisor do
  use DynamicSupervisor

  def start_link(init_arg) do
    DynamicSupervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, init_arg, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def start_child(foo, bar, baz) do
    # If MyWorker is not using the new child specs, we need to pass a map:
    # spec = %{id: MyWorker, start: {MyWorker, :start_link, [foo, bar, baz]}}
    spec = {MyWorker, foo: foo, bar: bar, baz: baz}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(init_arg) do
    DynamicSupervisor.init(
      strategy: :one_for_one,
      extra_arguments: [init_arg]
    )
  end
end
```

As you can see, they suggest to use a Keyword list here:

```
spec = {MyWorker, foo: foo, bar: bar, baz: baz}
```

It works only if you've implemented `MyWorker.start_link/1` as follows:

```
def start_link(args) do
   foo = Keyword.fetch!(args, :foo)
   bar = Keyword.fetch!(args, :bar)
   baz = Keyword.fetch!(args, :baz)
   Genserver.start_link(__MODULE__, {foo, bar, baz}, [])

def init({foo, bar, baz}) do
   # do something...
   state = {foo, bar, baz}
   {:ok, state}
```

In your case, if you change start_market/1 to:

```
  def start_market(market_id) do
      spec = {MarketService, market_id: market_id}
      DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
  end
```

It will not work because this MarketService.start_link/1 will fail:

```
 def start_link(market_id) when is_bitstring(market_id) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, market_id, name: via_tuple(market_id))
  end
```

market_id here is not a `bitstring` but a Keyword list. So you got to modify MarketService.start_link/1 function to:

```
  def start_link(args) when is_list(args) do
    market_id = Keyword.fetch!(args, :market_id)
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, market_id, name: via_tuple(market_id))
  end
```

And write a MarketService.init/1 as follows:

```
  def init(market_id) do
     # do something... Let's keep it simple for the example:
     state = market_id
     {:ok, state}
  end
```

## Helpful resources

- [José Valim's answer on a similar issue posted on Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/dynamicsupervisor-starting-child-with-more-than-one-argument/12998/2?u=nicogim)
- [Official module-based DynamicSupervisor documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DynamicSupervisor.html#module-migrating-from-supervisors-simple_one_for_one)
- A well-written [series of articles](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2018/07/09/pooltoy-a-toy-process-pool-manager-in-elixir-1-6/) about GenServer and Supervisors in Elixir...
- ...and [its corresponding source code](https://github.com/davidsulc/pool_toy)